# How to create custom shapes with \newcommand in TikZ and shift them

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I try to create treelike structures for basic arithmic with which students can learn to calculate. These trees should look like in the picture below just with more levels (to calculate more than one calculation).

[image]

To make it easier I want to define single elements with 3 squares (for the two summands and the solution) and a circle with the operator. So I defined a command which should give me this basic element.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\tree}[4]{
\draw[shift=(#1)] (-1,1.75) rectangle node{\footnotesize #2} (-.5,2.25);
\draw[shift=(#1)] (1,1.75) rectangle node{\footnotesize #3} (1.5,2.25);

\draw[shift=(#1)] (-.75,1.75)--(-.75,1.25)--(.05,1.25);
\draw[shift=(#1)] (1.25,1.75)--(1.25,1.25)--(.45,1.25);
\draw[shift=(#1)] (0.25,1.25) circle  (.2);
\draw[shift=(#1)] (.25,1.25)--+(2pt,0pt)--+(-2pt,0pt);
\draw[shift=(#1)] (.25,1.05)--(.25,.75);

\draw[shift=(#1)] (0,.25) rectangle node{\footnotesize #4} (.5,.75);
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tree{0,0}{100}{54}{8}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But the code above just keeps compiling without giving any error. Is there an easy way to define a precontructed TikZpicture which can just be inserted into another figure?

Greetings Laminator

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do get an error when testing that example.

Anyways, note that the options to a `\draw` and similar is a list of comma separated entries, so if the `<value>` in a `<key>=<value>` pair contains a comma, you need to use `<key>={<value>}`, otherwise the parser is confused. Hence, use `shift={(#1)}` and your example works as expected.

Anyways, some other suggestions:

#### `scope`

You could simplify your code a bit by using a `scope` environment:

```
\newcommand{\tree}[4]{
\begin{scope}[shift={(#1)}]
\draw ...
\end{scope}
}
```

#### Less manual drawing

Instead of drawing everything with explicit coordinates, you could place nodes relative to each other, and add the `draw` option to the nodes to draw their border.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newcommand{\tree}[4]{
\begin{scope}[
  shift={(#1)},
  every node/.style={
    draw,
    font=\footnotesize,
    node distance=3mm and 4mm
  }
]
\node  (a) {#4};
\node [circle,inner sep=2pt,above=of a] (op) {$-$};
\node [above left=of op] (b) {#2};
\node [above right=of op] (c) {#3};
\draw (a) -- (op) -| (b)
             (op) -| (c);
\end{scope}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tree{0,0}{100}{54}{8}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### `pic`s

TikZ 3.0 introduced the `pic` concept, which has the purpose of making small, reusable diagrams.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{
  pics/tree/.style args={#1#2#3}{
  code={
    \begin{scope}[
      every node/.style={
        draw,
        font=\footnotesize,
        node distance=3mm and 4mm
      }
    ] 
    \node  (a) {#3};
    \node [circle,inner sep=2pt,above=of a] (op) {$-$};
    \node [above left=of op] (b) {#1};
    \node [above right=of op] (c) {#2};
    \draw (a) -- (op) -| (b)
                 (op) -| (c);
    \end{scope}
       }
  }
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pic at (0,0) {tree={100}{54}{8}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks alot! The first paragraph already solved the problem. The scope environment helped to make it easier. The reason why I drew the operators + and - by my self was that in textmode they wheren't centered in the center of the circle. I obviously forgot to check math mode.
Is there a real difference between using a pic or a newcommand?

Comment: @Laminator There's a difference in the implementation of course. In use, it's mainly the syntax differences that you can see above.

Answer (score 5):

small variation of `\pic` concept in [Torbjørn T.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/586/torbj%C3%B8rn-t) answer:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc,
                positioning,
                quotes}

\tikzset{node distance = 7mm,
TBbox/.style = {draw, minimum width=12mm, minimum height=5mm,
                inner sep=1mm, outer sep=0mm},
TBsum/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=5mm, inner sep=0mm, font=\Large},
pics/TBB/.style n args  % Tree Building Block
             = {4}{code={
    \node (@tbb-1) [TBbox]    {#1};
    \node (@tbb-2) [TBbox, right=6mm of @tbb-1] {#2};
    \node (@tbb-3) [TBsum, below=1mm of $(@tbb-1.south)!0.5!(@tbb-2.south)$] {$#3$};
    \node (@tbb-4) [TBbox, below=3mm of @tbb-3] {#4};
    \coordinate    (-in1)  at (@tbb-1.north);
    \coordinate    (-in2)  at (@tbb-2.north);
    \coordinate    (-out)  at (@tbb-4.south);
    \draw[gray,->]   (@tbb-1) |- (@tbb-3);
    \draw[gray,->]   (@tbb-2) |- (@tbb-3);
    \draw[gray,->]   (@tbb-3) -- (@tbb-4);
                        }% end of code
                    },% end of style
every edge quotes/.style = {font=\footnotesize, inner sep=1mm, auto}
        }% endof tikzset

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\pic (a) at (0,0) {TBB={100}    % input 1
                       {54}     % input 2
                       {-}      % math operation
                       {8}      % result
                   };
\pic (b) [below=of a-out] {TBB={8}{2}{+}{10}};
    \draw[->]   (a-out) to ["copy"] (b-in1);
\pic (c) [below=of b-out] {TBB={10}{2}{\times}{\textbf{20}}};
    \draw[->]   (b-out) to ["copy"]  (c-in1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are building trees, why not to use `forest`?

```
\documentclass[margin=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
result/.style={
        draw, 
        minimum width=1cm,
        minimum height=6mm,
    },
data/.style={
        result, 
        edge path=\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
            (!u.parent anchor)-|(.child anchor)
            \forestoption{edge label};
    },
sign/.style={
    circle,
    minimum size=5mm,
    inner sep=2pt,
    draw
    },
for tree={grow'=90, 
    draw, 
    },
[9, result 
    [+, sign  
        [5, data
            [5, result, edge={<-} [+, sign [2, data][3,data]]]
        ]
        [4, data,
            [4, result, edge={<-} [-, sign [6, data][2,data]]]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]